# Xcode Warning: No Previous Prototype for Function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting the warning "No previous prototype for function 'LocStr'" on the following code:

```
NSString *LocStr(NSString *const key) {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:nil];
}
```

All code is working fine, is there a problem in submit the app to App Store with this warning? Is there a problem at all with this warning?

I can disable prototype warnings in Build Settings -> Missing Function Prototypes -> NO. But I wanted to be sure that this warning will not cause crashes and a rejection in the future.

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with being approved, but why not adding the prototype? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this. Which of the possibilities here might you have breached?

> no previous prototype for `foo'
>
> This means that GCC found a global function definition without seeing a prototype for the function.
>
> **o** If a function is used in more than one file, there should be a prototype for it in a header file somewhere. This keeps functions and
>   their uses from getting out of sync
>
> **o** If the function is only used in this file, make it static to
>    guarantee that it'll never be used outside this file
>    document that it's a local function

[[Source]](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/gcc-warnings.html)

Please don't just ignore warnings unless you know what they are, they may pose more of a threat than you realise.

---

Slightly tangential to your question, but you might find this easier to localize your strings. This is the solution I use:

`#define local(s) NSLocalizedString(s, s)`

Then just call `local(@"myStringKey");`

Comment: I'm not ignoring the warnings, thats why created this topic. :) On the other topics everyone says to ignore it of chance the Build Setting. And I find out an even easier solution, I added the STATIC on the line and the warning disappear: "static NSString *LocStr(NSString *const key)". Sorry if I'm a noob, but I'm just afraid of making a mistake with this code.

Comment: Asking questions is a good thing to do, I mean please don't even _consider_ ignoring warnings unless you know what you're ignoring.

You've picked a solution, but do you understand what it's done? By introducing the static keyword, you've told your program that you're not going to use the method outside of that class. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: To be more precise, the use of `static` in this case is not about use within a _file_ or _class_ but within a [compilation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).